# How can I prevent KML files from losing resolution when exporting them to an iPad?

Tags: arcmap, kml, ipad

I have created a KML from a polygon in ArcMap. The KML is the same in Google Earth as it is in ArcMap. When I load the KML onto my iPad, it loses resolution; it no longer has the level of detail it did. I've had the same issue with 3 iPad apps - GIS Pro, GIS Kit, and Avenza. This only happens to some KMLs (all polygons), others are fine. I have tried making the KML smaller and it's not a file size issue. I've tried running Simplify Polygon on the shapefile before converting it to a KML. The first image below shows the original KML, as it should be. The second shows how detail is lost once it's added to the iPad.

[image]

Comment: Why the tag for `arcmap` when it's the iPad app with the issue?

Comment: Because the KMLs were generated with ArcMap so I thought there might be an ArcMap solution. Like different options you can choose in the Layer to KML tool that might make the KMLs keep their integrity